# Can you call a function for all posts while inside a findbyid route in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a section in a blog that would show all posts that have the same tag as the post that a user has called. My show route for the post that is called by id is:

```
// SHOW
router.get("/:id", function(req,res){
    // find posts by mongoDB ID
    Posts.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.render("blog/show", {post: foundPost});
        }
    });
});
```

I am guessing I need to nest something like the following index GET route in the find by id route, but I am not sure how to get it in the route correctly:

```
router.get("/", function(req,res){
    // find all POSTS
    Posts.find({}, function(err, allPosts){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            // this is index because lots of paths are derived from it (landing pages are separate entities)
            res.render("blog/index",{Posts: allPosts});
        }
    }).sort({ create: 'desc' });
});
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. I just can't seem to get this worked out quite right.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing currently?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get Posts.find({}) (find all posts) as an object to pass in the findById res.render line. If I can get that in there then I know I can run a foreach loop on the results of the Posts.find({}) query in the EJS template show.

Comment: You can loop through allPosts array in the callback function itself before your current line "res.render("blog/index",{Posts: allPosts});"    Instead of allPosts, since you are looping through it, pass individual objects

Comment: can you show me exactly where to place it? I tried 1 loop before and got Posts undefined once. I  know it has to be before the res.render line, and then I am guessing you are editing the res.render("blog/show", {Posts: allPosts, post: foundPost}). Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using async/await will simplify the code. If you find any post by id then you can do a allpost find and pass it to template

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res){
    // find posts by mongoDB ID
    let foundPost = await Posts.findById(req.params.id);
    if (foundPost) {
        let allPosts = await Posts.find({});
        res.render("blog/show", { Posts: allPosts, post: foundPost });
    }

});
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for teaching me that and for your time helping me!